# Is it possible to loop datagridview to each excel file

Tags: c#, epplus

as above mentioned, is it possible to loop datagridview to each excel file, which mean each row generate each excel file accordingly.

What I've tried, the excel will prompt out to the last row of the datagridview.

The excel file will export based on the last row of datagridview. Is it possible to export each excel file, each row accordingly?

Any idea on that? Please advice. Thanks in advance.

```
 foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dgvOrder.Rows)
        {
            string templatePath = networkPath + @"\template" + @"\order.xlsx";

            string localFilePath = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments) + @"\Order\" + txtTitle.Text + "_" + txtOrder.Text + ".xlsx";

            FileInfo excelFile = new FileInfo(localFilePath);

            using (ExcelPackage package = new ExcelPackage(excelFile))
            {

                ExcelWorksheet worksheet = package.Workbook.Worksheets["Order"];


                DataSet ds = new DataSet();
                MySQLClass.query(ds, "SELECT * FROM order WHERE order_id = '" + order_id + "'");

                foreach (DataRow dr2 in ds.Tables[0].Rows)
                {
                    worksheet.Cells[2, 10].Value = txtTitle.Text;
                    worksheet.Cells[4, 10].Value = txtOrder.Text;
                    string text = row.Cells["order_id"].Value.ToString();
                    string myString = (text.Length > 1) ? text.Substring(text.Length - 2, 2) : text;

                    worksheet.Cells[5, 10].Value = myString;

                    package.Save();

                }

                System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(Path.GetFullPath(localFilePath));
            }

        }
```

Comment: what problem are you facing now?

Comment: @viveknuna Hi, the excel file will export based on the last row of datagridview. Is it possible to export each excel file, each row accordingly?